# How to map json array to two different array for chart

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular7

I am using chartjs chart in my angular application. And I have using a standart web api result for charts.

```
this.httpClient.get(this.REST_API_SERVER).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
  console.log(data);

})
```

data is:

```
[
   { "label": "city-1", "data1": 200},
   { "label": "city-2", "data1": 450},
   { "label": "city-2", "data1": 950},
]
```

or

```
[
   { "label": "city-1", "data1": 200, "data2": 60 },
   { "label": "city-2", "data1": 450, "data2": 40 },
   { "label": "city-3", "data1": 950, "data2": 78 },
]
```

I mean, `label` is label of chart and `data1`, `data2` or `data3` is values of chart.

So I want to split this response data to two different array like following.

```
var labels = [ "city-1", "city-3", "city-3"];
var data = [ 
              { "data": [ 200, 450, 950 ], "label": "data1" },
              { "data": [ 60,  40,  78 ], "label": "data2" }
           ];
```

is this possible in angular rxjs mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to transform the data in required format.

Iterate on given data and if an item with current label exists, then append values to its `data` array, if not create a new array item with current values.

```js
let input = [
   { "label": "city-1", "data1": 200, "data2": 60 },
   { "label": "city-2", "data1": 450, "data2": 40 },
   { "label": "city-3", "data1": 950, "data2": 78 },
];

let result = input.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc.labels = acc.labels || [];
  acc.labels.push(curr.label);
  acc.data = acc.data || [];

  Object.entries(curr).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (key !== "label") {
      let item = acc.data.find(item => item.label === key);
      if (item) {
        item.data.push(value);
      } else {
        acc.data.push({
          "data": [value],
          "label": key
        });
      }
    }
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

let labels = result.labels;
let data = result.data;

console.log("Labels", labels);
console.log("Data", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find here a working script:

```js
const list = [
   { "label": "city-1", "data1": 200, "data2": 60 },
   { "label": "city-2", "data1": 450, "data2": 40 },
   { "label": "city-3", "data1": 950, "data2": 78 },
]

const result = list.reduce((acc, item) => {

      const label = item['label'];
      acc[0].push(label);

      const keys = Object.keys(item).filter(key => key !== 'label');
      keys.forEach(key => {
        let labelItem = acc[1].find(value => value.label === key);
        if (!labelItem) {
          acc[1].push({ label:key, data: [item[key]] });
        } else {
          labelItem.data.push(item[key]);
        }
      });

      return acc;
    }, [[], []]);

console.log(result)
```

For typescript, you will need to add the type.